# HTML CANVAS to Input File

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

how can i set `<input type="file">` value from dynamic canvas?
i tried `$('input[type=file]').val(canvas.toDataUrl());` but nothing works and throw error like this one

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, it cannot be done.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: how so? The answer is that it is not possible.